# How to identify a hash-tagged word in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find the word that has been tagged in a string and set a variable to that tag

```
message = '#Identifier with some text'
tag = message.scan(/#\w+/)
```

This returns an array of the tags. I'm expecting there to be only 1 tagged word in the string so I would like it to return a word and not an array.

The text is generally not very long as it is being sent via sms.

Efficiency and speed of the function is obviously NB.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below uusing [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

> If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

```
message = '#Identifier with some text'
message[/#\w+/] # => "#Identifier"
```

Just remember : `\w+` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` . If you have any more characters followed by `#` symbol use an explicit character class. Like suppose `-`,`+` etc can be present also, so use the explicit character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]` as an example - `message[/#[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+/]`

Comment: Don't use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-+]`. While it works in this example, it's syntactically incorrect. `-` has special meaning inside `[...]` which results in the equivalent of `_..+`. In this particular case you got lucky, because the range `_..+` doesn't exist, but using the same syntax won't always be safe. Instead *ALWAYS* put `-` as the last character which is guaranteed to be automatically escaped as `-`, not a range character.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for letting me know this. If I could work with you, I guarantee a lot's of things I could learn from you. You have a huge knowledge..